# How can I do multiple backgrounds in one div tag?

Tags: css, background-image

First off: http://jsfiddle.net/83FDf/

I have an image set as my "menu's" background... It has blue gradient, rounded corners, and then at the bottom it has white with slight shadow under the blue menu.

[image: my image]

Is it possible to recreate it using pure css on one div?

html:

```
<div class="main_content"></div>
```

css:

```
.main_content
{
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/mionT7y.jpg) no-repeat center top #fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 0 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible, note that the amount of rules required for shadows and gradients are due to different browsers requiring different syntax (`-moz-` is the Firefox vendor prefix, etc.). Here are some handy tools for coming up with cross-browser gradients and box shadows easily.

- [CSS3 Box Shadow Generator](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/)
- [CSS3 Gradient Generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)
- [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator (more options like color stops)](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Read more about linear gradients and box shadows here:

- [Mozilla developer linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient)
- [Mozilla developer box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/box-shadow)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/BHE47/1/)

```
.main_content
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 0 50px;
    /*background-color:#00F;*/

    /* Add rounded border to top left and top right */
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;

    /* Apply the gradient as a background image */
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(79,110,189) 0%, rgb(44,188,207) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(79,110,189) 0%, rgb(44,188,207) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(79,110,189) 0%, rgb(44,188,207) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(79,110,189) 0%, rgb(44,188,207) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(79,110,189) 0%, rgb(44,188,207) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgb(79,110,189)),
        color-stop(1, rgb(44,188,207))
    );

    /* Apply white shadow on bottom */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 4px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 4px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

body {
    margin:0;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Comment: Can you add comments that are mega descriptive so others (and I, mostly me...) can learn from this?

Comment: Elaborated a bit and added more quality links, it's most just vendor prefixes.

Comment: `box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px #FFF;` works fine, in the example above it's actually coming out at 75% transparency though so it's a little different. You can't do hex and have alpha.

Comment: For the record, this is closer to my original image: http://jsfiddle.net/BHE47/2/

Comment: Wait, now I can't seem to figure out how to make it white... Any help? http://pachonk.com/alex/test/pachonkadmin.html

Comment: That's because you're using `#888` as your `box-shadow`. Try something like this: `box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px -3px #FFF;` The new `-3px` reduces the size of the shadow so it will only come out the bottom.

Comment: It looks like you just want a border from that picture `border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;`

Comment: How do I make the white part is what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Of what i understood about your question, you could use multiple images in comma separated form in your css and give them a position too :

background-image: url(../pix/logo_quirksmode.gif), url(../pix/logo_quirksmode_inverted.gif);